# Openssh slow on solaris server

Tags: ssh, solaris, openssh

ssh is slow on solaris server and is getting stuck at the following place.

```
-130-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxx1:xxxx $ ssh -vvv xxxxxx
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xxxxxx [xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: Wrote 864 bytes for a total of 885
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 909
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 153/320
debug2: bits set: 1651/3191
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: Wrote 416 bytes for a total of 1325
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host xxxxxx filename /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host xxxxxx filename /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host xxxxxx filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host xxxxxx filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host xx.xxx.xxx.xxx filename /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host xx.xxx.xxx.xxx filename /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host xx.xxx.xxx.xxx filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host xx.xxx.xxx.xxx filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host xxxxxx filename /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host xxxxxx filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug2: no key of type 0 for host xxxxxx
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host xxxxxx filename /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts2
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host xxxxxx filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host xxxxxx filename /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host xxxxxx filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug2: no key of type 2 for host xxxxxx
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host xxxxxx filename /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts2
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host xxxxxx filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host xxxxxx filename /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host xxxxxx filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug2: no key of type 3 for host xxxxxx
The authenticity of host 'xxxxxx (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 20:b6:4c:3a:d7:fd:ef:68:44:6d:63:b2:b6:49:f8:2b.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'xxxxxx,xx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug2: bits set: 1576/3191
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 1341
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug3: Wrote 52 bytes for a total of 1393
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /usr/local/lib/memento-pkcs11.so (0x55c00fcdcfb0)
debug2: key: /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55c00fcd9980)
debug2: key: /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug3: Wrote 84 bytes for a total of 1477
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug3: Trying to reverse map address xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1372003359' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1372003359' not found

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /usr/local/lib/memento-pkcs11.so
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 388 bytes for a total of 1865
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: SHA1 fp 91:af:77:0c:09:b9:c5:06:69:79:43:37:72:8e:bf:cd:6c:5d:f8:ad
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 91:af:77:0c:09:b9:c5:06:69:79:43:37:72:8e:bf:cd:6c:5d:f8:ad
debug3: Wrote 660 bytes for a total of 2525
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug3: Wrote 136 bytes for a total of 2661
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LD_LIBRARY_PATH
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env PS1
debug3: Ignored env HISTCONTROL
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env CVS_RSH
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env G_BROKEN_FILENAMES
debug3: Ignored env _
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: fd 4 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: Wrote 544 bytes for a total of 3205
```

Below is the ssh version being used:

```
Sun_SSH_1.1.6, SSH protocols 1.5/2.0, OpenSSL 0x0090704f
```

Below is the sshd config file:

```
Protocol 2
UseDNS yes  
PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
Subsystem sftp /xxx/openssh/sftp-server
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/local/bin/ldap_ssh_authorizedkeys
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody
```

Comment: Did you restart the SSH daemon after turning off GSSAPIAuthentication?

Comment: What are you doing when it's slow?  The information you provide to identify "stuck at the following place" isn't very clear - there's no way to read that and know what's going on.

Comment: Yes @kusalananda

Comment: Edited and added the complete debug logs.

Comment: Try creating a `.hushlogin` file in your home directory on the remote server.  If that fixes the problem, the remote server was likely getting hung up doing disk quota checks on all mounted filesystems.  If there are a lot of filesystems, or if any remote NFS file server is slow responding, it will hang your login.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to create these settings:

```
GSSAPIAuthentication no
GSSAPIKeyExchange no
GSSAPIStoreDelegatedCredentials no
LookupClientHostnames no
```